# Show specific modal depending on url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How can I show a specific modal depending on the URL?

I'm using as a responsive framework Bootstrap.

I have two modals (in reality there are many):

1. privvilege_10
2. privvilege_11

The modals are opened using url and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#privilege_10') != -1) {
    $('#privilege_10').modal('show');
  }

});
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#privilege_11') != -1) {
    $('#privilege_11').modal('show');
  }

});
```

If the URL is **index.php#privilege_10** then, *privilege_10*'s modal will be opened and if the URL is **index.php#privilege_11** then, *privilege_11*'s modal will be opened.

As there are many modals like this adding code for each modals will be very long.

So how can I do it in just writing the code once? (like looping it)

`if(window.location.href.indexOf('#privilege_10') != -1)` this could be changed to check whether the url contains **#privilege**, if *yes*:

`$('#privilege_10').modal('show');` this should be changed to **`$('what ever the url contains [#privilege_10 or #privilege_11]').modal('show');`** Just like what we do in *php* (`$_GET['']`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking for a specific modal, let the hash value of the URL be the ID for the modal. So all you need to do is get the hash value and then use that to call the modal.

```
$(window.location.hash).modal('show');
```

If the modal does not exist, nothing will happen. If it does, the modal will show. Note that this example does not have any checks for `window.location.hash`.

Comment: Just realized that I posted the same answer. I had the window open to answer and got distracted by something else. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the anchor from the URL and then you could verify that it's correct and if it is, pop up the modal.

The function I would make:

```
$(function () {
    var anchor = window.location.hash;
    if (anchor.split('_')[0] == '#privilege') {
       $(anchor).modal('show');
    }
}
```